# Установка Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с установкой Oracle 11g на домашний компьютер. На сколько я понял ругается преимущественно на оперативку. На компьютере 2 гигабайта оперативной памяти. Вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме памяти ругается ещё на что то но пока что думаю стоит разобраться с памятью. Вот скрин загруженности памяти на момент чека:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понимаю 728 + 922 мегабайта у меня есть на компьютере но почему то ругается. Что не так, подскажите пожалуйста?
Вот моё подключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65176/discussion-on-question-by---oracle-11g).

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблемы с листенером.
Чтобы увидеть, видит ли листенер экземпляр базы данных, введите в cmd:

```
lsnrctl services
```

Если будет сообщение о том, что сервисов нет, то тогда необходимо зарегистрировать. Для этого измените файл, находящийся в $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora и добавьте туда строки:

```
(SID_DESC = 
(GLOBAL_DBNAME = <ваш_SID>) 
(ORACLE_HOME = C:\путь\к\oracle_home\) 
(SID_NAME = <ваш_SID>) 
) 
)
```